# Using data.table to assign the best of response in r

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset like this:

```
dt <- data.table(USUBJID = c(rep("001-001", 4), rep("001-002", 4), rep("001-003", 3)),BOR_candidate = c(NA,"CR","CR","SD",NA,"SD","SD","N",NA,"SD","SD"))
```

What I want to do is to detect values in BOR_candidate by each USUBJID. The rules are as follows:

1. If USUBJID has any complete response(CR), then all BOR for that USUBJID should be CR.
2. else if USUBJID has any partial response(PR), then all BOR for that USUBJID should be PR.
3. else if USUBJID has any stable disease(SD), then all BOR for that USUBJID should be SD.
4. else assign N.

So the result I want is like this:

```
dt <- data.table(USUBJID = c(rep("001-001", 4), rep("001-002", 4), rep("001-003", 3)),
             BOR_candidate = c(NA,"CR","CR","SD",NA,"SD","SD","N",NA,"SD","SD"),
             BOR = c(rep("CR", 4), rep("SD", 4), rep("SD", 3)))
```

I have tried the code below but it didn't work out what I want. Any suggestion would be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

```
dt[,BORR := ifelse(grepl("CR", dt[,2]),"CR",ifelse(grepl("PR",dt[,2]),"PR",ifelse(grepl("SD",dt[,2]), "SD", "N"))),by = USUBJID]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another option:

```
resp <- c("CR", "PR", "SD")
dt[order(USUBJID, match(BOR_candidate, resp)), BOR2 := {
        notTop <- USUBJID==shift(USUBJID, fill="")
        ix <- nafill(replace(.I, notTop, NA_integer_), "locf")
        replace(BOR_candidate[ix], is.na(BOR_candidate[ix]), "N")
    }]
```

output:

```
    USUBJID BOR_candidate BOR BOR2
 1: 001-001          <NA>  CR   CR
 2: 001-001            CR  CR   CR
 3: 001-001            CR  CR   CR
 4: 001-001            SD  CR   CR
 5: 001-002          <NA>  SD   SD
 6: 001-002            SD  SD   SD
 7: 001-002            SD  SD   SD
 8: 001-002             N  SD   SD
 9: 001-003          <NA>  SD   SD
10: 001-003            SD  SD   SD
11: 001-003            SD  SD   SD
12: 001-004             N   N    N
13: 001-005          <NA>   N    N
```

data:

```
dt <- data.table(USUBJID = c(rep("001-001", 4), rep("001-002", 4), rep("001-003", 3), "001-004", "001-005"),
    BOR_candidate = c(NA,"CR","CR","SD",NA,"SD","SD","N",NA,"SD","SD","N",NA),
    BOR = c(rep("CR", 4), rep("SD", 4), rep("SD", 3), "N", "N"))
```

---

timing code:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
nr <- 1e6
dt <- data.table(USUBJID=as.character(rep(1:(nr/4), each=4)),
    BOR_candidate=sample(c("SD","PR","CR","N",NA), nr, TRUE))
DT0 <- copy(dt)
DT1 <- copy(dt)

mtd0 <- function() {
    DT0[, BOR := "N" ]
    for (cand in c("SD", "PR", "CR")) {
        DT0[, BOR := if (any(BOR_candidate == cand, na.rm = TRUE)) cand else BOR,
            by = .(USUBJID) ]
    }
    DT0
}

mtd1 <- function() {
    resp <- c("CR", "PR", "SD")
    DT1[order(USUBJID, match(BOR_candidate, resp)), BOR := {
            notTop <- USUBJID==shift(USUBJID, fill="")
            ix <- nafill(replace(.I, notTop, NA_integer_), "locf")
            replace(BOR_candidate[ix], is.na(BOR_candidate[ix]), "N")
        }]
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=1L, mtd0=a0 <- mtd0(), mtd1=a1 <- mtd1())
fsetequal(a0, a1)
#[1] TRUE
```

timings:

```
Unit: seconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 mtd0 4.796831 4.796831 4.796831 4.796831 4.796831 4.796831     1
 mtd1 1.454013 1.454013 1.454013 1.454013 1.454013 1.454013     1
```

Answer (score 1):

In `dplyr`, we can `group_by` and use `case_when` to check for various conditions.

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  group_by(USUBJID) %>%
  mutate(BOR = case_when(any(BOR_candidate == "CR") ~ "CR", 
                         any(BOR_candidate == "PR") ~ "PR", 
                         any(BOR_candidate == "SD") ~ "SD",
                         TRUE ~ "N"))

#  USUBJID BOR_candidate BOR  
#   <chr>   <chr>         <chr>
# 1 001-001 NA            CR   
# 2 001-001 CR            CR   
# 3 001-001 CR            CR   
# 4 001-001 SD            CR   
# 5 001-002 NA            SD   
# 6 001-002 SD            SD   
# 7 001-002 SD            SD   
# 8 001-002 N             SD   
# 9 001-003 NA            SD   
#10 001-003 SD            SD   
#11 001-003 SD            SD
```

`data.table` has `fcase` which behaves similarly and is available under development version.

Comment: I found it interesting (when trying your answer) that this does not need `na.rm=TRUE` while mine does.

Comment: I think that is because `case_when` treats `NA` as `FALSE` and moves on to next condition.

Comment: Good call, that's probably it. As much as I hate it when I get the error (`missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`), it does indicate where my assumptions of the conditional logic might be flawed. \*shrug\*

Answer (score 1):

```r
dt[, BOR := "N" ]
for (cand in c("SD", "PR", "CR")) {
  dt[, BOR := if (any(BOR_candidate == cand, na.rm = TRUE)) cand else BOR,
     by = .(USUBJID) ]
}
dt
#     USUBJID BOR_candidate BOR
#  1: 001-001          <NA>  CR
#  2: 001-001            CR  CR
#  3: 001-001            CR  CR
#  4: 001-001            SD  CR
#  5: 001-002          <NA>  SD
#  6: 001-002            SD  SD
#  7: 001-002            SD  SD
#  8: 001-002             N  SD
#  9: 001-003          <NA>  SD
# 10: 001-003            SD  SD
# 11: 001-003            SD  SD
```

The *slight* inefficiency of this is that it is re-assigning `BOR` multiple times as multiple matches are found in subsequent `for` iterations.